# Converting KeyBinding to MouseBinding in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm working with a DataGrid.

I currently have the following XAML:

```
<dg:DataGrid lc:DataGridPackage.QueryGrid="{Binding myGrid}">
    ...
    <dg:DataGrid.Resources>
        <lc:CommandReference x:Key="myCommand" Command="{Binding myCommandActionItem}" />
    </dg:DataGrid.Resources>

    <dg:DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="D" Command="{StaticResource myCommand}" />
```

It works fine. I click on a row in the datagrid, press Ctrl+D and the command executes (in this case, refreshing a row).

However, if I change the KeyBinding to a MouseBinding:

```
<MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{StaticResource myCommand}">
```

I get the error "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the the 'Command' property of type 'MouseBinding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it should be `<MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{StaticResource myCommand}"`

Comment: Sorry, that is actually what I already had. `<MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{StaticResource CdsAxesRefresh}">`

It gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{StaticResource myCommand}" />
```

You can't use Binding markup extension on Command property. As the error says, Command is not DependencyProperty.

Comment: I get the same error, whether I use `<MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{StaticResource myCommand}">` or `<MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding myCommand}">`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you handle every Event to Binding Situation in a Behavior? 
This way you could easily assign your events, check for modifiers and send a command to the viewmodel.

If you want I can provide some code for this scenario.